# Diagonalization of block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following matrix:
\begin{pmatrix}iA & I\\
I & 0
\end{pmatrix}

where A hermitian matrix. How can I found its diagonal form using A diagonal form?

Comment: I don't think that there is a way to use the diagonalization of $A$ to diagonlize your matrix

Answer (score 1):

Take $U$ that diagonalize $A$ and compute $\begin{pmatrix}U^*&0\\0&U^*\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}iA&I\\I&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}U&0\\0&U\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}iD&I\\I&0\end{pmatrix}=K$ where $D$ is the diagonal form of $A$. Now you can find the eigenvalues of the obtained matrix as $\det(K-\lambda I)=\det 
((iD-\lambda I)(-\lambda I)-I)=0$, i'll let you finish.

Answer (score 0):

Your matrix $M$ is not Hermitian, so there cannot exist a non-singular matrix $P$ such that $P^*MP$ is  real diagonal.